# Magical Numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics

A natural number $N$ is said to be nice if we obtain a divisor of $N$ by erasing one of its digits. A positive integer $X$ is said to be magical if:

- $X$ has distinct digits.
- $X$ is nice.
- The divisor obtained in the above case is magical.

Moreover all one digit numbers are magical. Find the largest magical number.

Let me add some example so that the problem becomes clear.

The number 65 is nice: Deleting 6 gives 5 and 5|65.

The number 625 is magical: 5|25 and 25|625.

Comment: $(1)$ Are we allowed to erase a digit leading to a number with a leading zero ? $(2)$ "Divisor" means "non-trivial divisor" , right ?

Comment: @Peter: Consider that a number cannot begin with 0. Divisors include 1 too.

Comment: Is one choice of the deleted digit sufficient or does every choice have to work?

Comment: There exists a digit which can be deleted to give a number that divides the original number. For instance 65 is nice since erasing 6 gives 5 and 5|65.

Comment: Based on the results of a search program, the largest magical number is  $146250$, with various descending sequences, one of which is
$$
146250
\rightarrow 
16250
\rightarrow
1250
\rightarrow
250
\rightarrow
25
\rightarrow
5
$$

Comment: Doesn't $1350\to135\to15\to5$ make $1350$ a counterexample to the claim about how a magical number of four or more digits must end?

Comment: @Barry Cipra: Yea you're right. I'll fix it

Comment: @quasi, the OP has removed the assertion about how a magical number with four or more digits must end. Does that affect the search program you used?

Comment: @Barry Cipra: No, I didn't use any conditions other than the definition.

Comment: I would like to know the source of this problem.

Comment: I got the problem from a friend of mine. But the primary source is from some problem set on elementary number theory. ( sadly without solutions.)

Comment: Note: In my search program, I assumed the digit removal was not allowed to result in a leading zero digit. In other words, each digit removed results in a number with exactly one less digit (with leading zeros not allowed). With that assumption, the largest magical number is $146250$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $n=10^{k+1}b+10^kd+a$ with $a,b,d,k\in\Bbb N$ satisfying

- $10\nmid n$
- $a<10^k$
- $d<10$

Let $m=10^kb+a$ which is the number obtained from $n$ by erasing the $k$-th digit $d$ and assume $m\mid n$, so that $n$ is a nice number.

> If $a=0$ and $b\neq 0$, then $n<100$.

*Proof.*
We have $k=0$ and $b\mid d$, hence $n$ has two digits so that $n<100$.

> If $a\neq 0$ and $b\neq 0$, then $n\leq 180625$.

*Proof.*
Let
\begin{align}
&u=\frac{10^k}{\gcd(a,10^k)}&
&v=\frac a{\gcd(a,10^k)}
\end{align}
so that $1<v<u$ and $\gcd(u,v)=1$.
We have
\begin{align}
\frac nm
=\frac{10^{k+1}b+10^kd+a}{10^kb+a}
=1+10^k\frac{9b+d}{10^kb+a}
=1+u\frac{9b+d}{ub+v}
\end{align}
and since $\gcd(u,ub+v)=1$, we have
$$(ub+v)\mid(9b+d)\tag{1}$$

From $ub+v\leq 9b+d$ we get
$$u\leq 9+\frac{d-v}b\leq 17\tag{2}$$
hence the only possible values for $u$ are $2,4,5,8,10,16$.

If we let $q=\frac{9b+d}{ub+v}\in\Bbb N$, then we get
$$b=\frac{qv-d}{9-qu}<9\tag{3}$$
For if $q <9/u $, then $9-qu\geq 1$ hence
$$b\leq 9v/u-d<9$$
while if $q>9/u$, then $qu-9\geq 1$ hence
$$b <d-qv <d\leq 9$$

Consequently, the number of digits of $n $ is $k+1$ which is determined by $u $, hence largest nice number $n$ of this form is obtained for $u=16$.
In that case we have $q=1$ for otherwise $qu-9\geq 23$ hence the contradiction 
$$b\leq\frac {d-qv}{23}<\frac 9 {23}<1$$
Then $b=\frac{d-v}7$ from which $d=8$ and $v=1$, giving the nice number $n=180625$.

> The largest magical number is $903125$.

Let $n$ be the largest magical number not divisible by $10$ and assume $n>180625$.
Then $b=0$, $a\neq 0$ and $d\neq 0$ which implies $a\mid 10^kd$ with $k\geq 5$.
Since $n$ doesn't contains repeated digits, it has at most $10$ digits, we have $k\leq 9$ and $a\geq 10^{k-2}$.
Thus $10^3\leq a<10^9$ and $a|10^9d$ which reduces the possibility for $a$ to be one of the $28$ numbers satisfying:
\begin{align}
&2^{10}|a|2^{12}&
&2^9\cdot 3|a|2^{10}\cdot 3^2&
&2^8\cdot 7|a|2^9\cdot 7\\
&5^5|a|5^9&
&5^4\cdot 3|a|5^9\cdot 3^2&
&5^4\cdot 7|a|5^9\cdot 7
\end{align}

Note that $2^h\mid a$ implies $k\geq h-3$ and $a\geq 10^{h-5}$: this shows that $a$ cannot satisfy any of the conditions in the first line.

If $5\mid a$, then $a\equiv 5\pmod{10}$, hence $d\neq 5$.
Thus $5^h\mid a$ implies $k\geq h$ and $a\geq 10^{h-2}$ which excludes some cases from the second line.
Moreover, $5^3\cdot 7\equiv 5^2\cdot 7\equiv 75\pmod{100}$ which implies $5\cdot 7\nmid a$.

A direct computation on the few remaining cases, shows that $a=5^5$ with $d=9$ and $k=5$ is the largest solution giving $n=903125$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but there are some things I do not understand. why $(3)$? Shouldn't it be $\le9$ because $b$ is a decimal digit? Also I don't understand your reasoning starting with "Consequently". Why is the largest $n$ obtained for $u=16?$Why is $q=1$ in this case?

Comment: in $(4)$ I don't find $a=2^95^83$, but $10^3\leq a<10^9$ and $a|10^9d$ holds for $d=3$

Comment: Note that $a=2^9\cdot 5^8\cdot 3$ is excluded because $10\mid a$ and it is assumed $10\nmid n$.

Answer (score 6):

The largest magical number is $903125$. To verify it, remove the leftmost digit repeatedly.

There are $326$ nontrivial (multi-digit) magical numbers, and traversing them all by a simple depth-first search requires checking $11982$ divisibility relations. If you find some shortcuts, you might be able to reduce the labor to a couple thousand steps. I still wouldn't do this by hand!

---

Here is some terse Python code:

```
num_trials = 0
stack = [str(digit) for digit in range(1, 10)]
parents = {}
while stack:
  x = stack.pop()
  for position in range(len(x) + 1):
    for digit in range(10):
      if str(digit) not in set(x):
        y = x[:position] + str(digit) + x[position:]
        if y not in parents:
          num_trials += 1
          if int(y) % int(x) == 0:
            parents[y] = x
            stack.append(y)

numbers = sorted(set(int(s) for s in parents))
print 'Performed %d modulo operations.' % num_trials
print 'Found %d magical numbers.' % len(numbers)
print 'Examples:', ', '.join(str(x) for x in reversed(numbers) if x >= 10000)

lineage = [str(numbers[-1])]
while lineage[-1] in parents:
  lineage.append(parents[lineage[-1]])
print 'Lineage of the winner:', ' <- '.join(lineage)
```

Output:

```
Performed 11982 modulo operations.
Found 326 magical numbers.
Examples: 903125, 803125, 703125, 609375, 603125, 403125, 180625, 146250, 93750, 91250, 90625, 90375, 90125, 81250, 80625, 80125, 71250, 70625, 70125, 63750, 61250, 60375, 60125, 41250, 40625, 40125, 31250, 30625, 30125, 24750, 16250, 14625, 10625
Lineage of the winner: 903125 <- 03125 <- 3125 <- 125 <- 25 <- 5
```

---

Edit: Per the comments, if you disallow leading zeros by requiring `y[0] != '0'`, then there are fewer candidates to work through:

```
Performed 6156 modulo operations.
Found 227 magical numbers.
Examples: 146250, 93750, 91250, 81250, 71250, 63750, 61250, 41250, 31250, 24750, 16250, 14625
Lineage of the winner: 146250 <- 16250 <- 1250 <- 250 <- 50 <- 5
```

---

Edit 2: For an example of a "trick" that reduces the labor, let's apply miracle173's **Observation 1**, using this code to bail out of the inner loop:

```
if len(x) >= 3:
  if position == len(x):
    if digit != 0:
      continue
  elif position > 1:
    continue
```

This change halves the amount of work. It now takes $3447$ modulo operations to find the $227$ magical numbers up to $146250$, or allowing leading zeros, $6120$ modulo operations to find the $326$ magical numbers up to $903125$.

Comment: By "perfect" numbers, you mean "magical" numbers?

Comment: @GerryMyerson Thank you, fixed. In my defense, both words have 7 letters including a repeated vowel, so they're basically the same word.

Comment: +1.  Nice, I was thinking this would best be solved in code.  Any thoughts, anyone, about which bases (if any) have an infinite number of magical numbers (equivalently, there is no largest magical number)?

Comment: @BrianTung "this would best be solved in code" is definitely not my opinion and not the reason why I started a bounty :-). Nevertheless this answer will earn the bounty if now other answers are posted.

Comment: @miracle173: Well, I suppose "best" isn't the most accurate word. :-)  I suspect I mean most straightforward.  Perhaps I'm just not very sanguine about an elegant demonstration.

Comment: @BrianTung about an infinite number of magic numbers see my post (simple observation). This is a problem from a collection of "elementary number theory problems", so I think there will be a solution that one can get by hand. I think I am pretty near to solve the problem for the first type of magic numbers where the second digit will be destroyed in the first step.

Answer (score 1):

**Some observations**

**Simple Observation**

- There is a maximal magic number, because there are magic numbers and a magic number can have at most 10 digits.
- If there is a $k$-digit magic number then there is a $k-1$ digit magic number.

**Observation 1**

Assume we have a $k$-digit number, $k\ge3$, starting left with digits $x$, $y$ and $z$.
So the number is $n_1:=(100x+10y+z)M+u$ and the divisor generated by erasing a digit is $n_2:=(10x+y)M+v$, if we do not erase one of the leading digits $x$ and $y$, and the following holds:
$$
M=10^{k-3}\\
0\le v,u\lt M \\
0\le y,z \le 9 \\
1 \le x \le 9\\
$$
for the quotient $q:=\frac{n_1}{n_2}$ we get
$$
q=\frac{n_1}{n_2}=\\
\frac{(100x+10y+z)M+u}{(10x+y)M+v}= \\ 
\frac{(100x+10y)M+10v-10v+zM+u}{(10x+y)M+v}=\\
\frac{10(10x+y)M+10v-10v+zM+u}{(10x+y)M+v}=\\
10+\frac{-10v+zM+u}{(10x+y)M+v}\\
$$
And if we set $d:=\frac{-10v+zM+u}{(10x+y)M+v}$ we can see that

$$
d=\frac{-10v+zM+u}{(10x+y)M+v}\lt\frac{9M+M}{(10x+y)M+v}\le\frac{10M}{10M}\le1\\
d=\frac{-10v+zM+u}{(10x+y)M+v} \gt \frac{-10M+9M}{10M}=-\frac{1}{10}
$$
and therefore $$q=10+d \in (9.9,11).$$ But $q$ is an integer, so $q=10$ and that means that the righmost digit of $n_1$  is a $0$.

*So if $n_1$ is a **nice** number and $n_2$ is a divisor of $n_1$ that we get by erasing a digit of $n_1$, then the digit must be one of the two most left digits of $n_1$ or the most right digit of $n_1$. In the latter case this most right digit is a $0.$*

**Observation 2**
In the following we can assume that $M=10^8$. This may introduce some additional $0$ at the end of the numbers, but that does not matter, they can be removed.

We have $$
M=10^8\\
0\le u\lt M \\
0\le y \le 9 \\
1 \le x \le 9\\
$$
and now we erase the second digit. For the quotient $q:=\frac{n_1}{n_2}$ we get
$$
q=\frac{n_1}{n_2}=\\
\frac{(10x+y)M+u}{xM+u}= \\ 
\frac{(9x+y)M+xM+u}{xM+u}= \\ 
$$
$$
1+\frac{(9x+y)M}{xM+u} \tag{1}\ 
$$

So we have
$$q \in \left(\frac{10x+1}{x+1},\frac{10x+9}{x}\right] \tag{2}\ 
$$

From this we can calculate for every $x$ a lower bound $q_1$ and an upper bound $q_2$ for $q.$

From $(1)$ we also get

$$u(q-1)=((10-q)x+y)M\tag{3}$$
and further

$$q  \in [\frac{10x+y+1}{x+1}, \frac{10x+y}{x}]\tag{4}$$

*If we have a number with at least two digits and we get a divisor by erasing the second digit from left, then the quotient of this number and the divisor is an integer restricted by $(2)$. For all values of $x$ the minimum value $q_1$ and the maximum value $q_2$ are show in the following table.*

```
x  q1 q2
1  6  19 
2  8  14 
3  8  13 
4  9  12 
5  9  11 
6  9  11 
7  9  11 
8 10  11 
9 10  11
```

From $(3)$ we can make a lot of conclusions:

1. $q-1$ cannot be $0$, so if $((10-q)x+y)$ then $u=0$. But $u=0$ is not interesting because these are the 3-digit numbers $100x+y$ ending with $0$.
2. if $q-1=((10-q)x+y)$ then these values can be ignored because $u=M$ follows which is impossible.
3. if $q-1$ is divided by a prime $p \notin \{2,5\}$ then $p$ must divide $((10-q)x+y)$. From this often follows 1. or 2.

**Observation 3**

We can eliminate som $q$ by further investigations that use $(3)$.
**case $q=10$**
$$\implies 9u=yM$$
this implies either $y=u=0$ which min the number is $10x$, which is not interesting or 
$y=9$ and $u=M$ which contradicts $u<M$. so we can exclude $q=9$

**case $q=12,14,18$**

$$\implies 13u=(-3x+y)M \implies 13=y-3x\implies y=13+3x$$ which can't happen because $y<10$

$q=14$ and $q=18$ is similar to this case.

**case $q=19$**

we have $x=1$ and therefor $y=9$ and $(10-q)x+y=0$, so $u=0$ and we can ignore this case.

**case $\gcd(q-1,M)=1$**

From $(3)$ follows $M|u$. $u<M$, so $u=0$

so we can skip $q=8,10,12,14,18$

(will be continued, I hope)

Comment: Nice! I've edited my answer to include Observation 1; it halves the amount of work.